# How to drop column based on column name not starting with another column name

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I have below 2 input dataframe

```
df1 = {
ID : 1,
region : GBR,
Fruit : Apple
}

df2 = {
ID : 1,
GBR_Price : 12
EUR_Price : 15
US_Price : 8
}
```

Outcome required :-

```
df1 = {
ID : 1,
region : GBR,
GBR_Price : 12,
Fruit : Apple
}
```

I would like to join the above two dataframes for populating the region specific price as per the region in df1 and any other regional price should drop off.

As per above example, the record in df1 is for region GBR, so when the join happens it should only bring the GBR_price from df2 and drop the EUR_PRICE & US_PRICE which are any other regional prices that would vary on every other record.

I tried using below command but this is giving me syntax error

`df1 = df1.join(df2, df1.ID = df2.ID).drop(df2.id).drop(df2.filter(regex = '^(?!df1.region)*')))`

Comment: `^(?!df1.region)*` matches any string, since the lookahead is optional.

Comment: Specify what your syntax error is (full error stack)? because based on your definition of ```df1``` it will through a syntax error as well

Answer (score 0):

Give the full error stack, but based on your code now, you'll get a syntax error on how you've defined `df1` and `df2`

Correct Format - (specify strings with quotes):

````
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
'ID' : [1],
'region' : ['GBR'],
'Fruit' : ['Apple']
}) ```
````